# <c:forEach> JSTL tag crashing the WebSphere 7 server

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm using Spring MVC to pass a ArrayList object from my Controller to JSP and I want to iterate it over there using JSTL (forEach), but it is always crashing Java server after 10~20 seconds loading the page. It's not throwing any exception.

Trying to use "c:out" to print the String representing the array works fine. Same to not empty validation. It always crashes when program reaches the forEach.

**SIMPLIFIED EXAMPLE BELOW**

**Controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, params = "create")
public ModelAndView createBranch (Branch branch) throws FxtrmServiceException, JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{

    ModelAndView branchMV = new ModelAndView("branch");


    ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    array1.add("test1");
    array1.add("test2");

    branchMV.addObject("alertMap1", array1);

    populateAutoCompletes(branchMV);

    return branchMV;    
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"  %>
(...)
    <c:if test="${not empty alertMap1}">
        <c:forEach items="${alertMap1}" var="entry1">
                    <c:out value="${entry1}"/><br>                            
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?  Does the server become unresponsive?

Comment: In your Spring controller, log the size of the map/array.

Comment: @matts The server stops responding and I need to restart it.

Comment: @parsifal Can you clarify how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Does `populateAutoCompletes` do anything related to the `alertMap1` object?

Comment: @matts nothing related... :(

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `populateAutoCompletes(branchMV)`?

Comment: @clav yes, but the problem remains

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `<c:out value="${entry1}"/>` tag with just `${entry1}`

Comment: When the "server stops responding," is that to everything? Can you connect to the server from another browser?

Comment: Also, what does the thread dump look like? You don't say what platform you're on, and the methods to get the dump will differ depending on Windows/Linux/other. The Websphere docs should help you if you don't already know how to do this.

Comment: @parsifal yes, stops responding and it crashes. I can't connect from any client. The only way is to restart it.

Comment: @parsifal I'm running on Windows 7, local server for development. I'm not sure what is the tread dump. Can you help me on it? Tks.

Comment: Here is some information about generating a thread dump: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124672/java-stack-dump-on-windows

Comment: However, if that's truly the code that you're executing, there is no way that it could completely lock up your server. It's possible that you have a corrupted JVM or Websphere install, and is probably worth reinstalling. If it's not the actual code, you need to post the actual code.

Comment: I just reinstalled RAD and it worked. Thank you all.