# JBOSS Application Server getting hanged on Production environment

Tags: jboss

Can someone please give detailed way to monitor JBOSS app server ? 
The production application running on JBOSS server starts working fine after restarting the server. How do I identify what is the cause behind it?

Answer (score 0):

To see what is "hung", try getting a thread dump from your JBoss instance by running it in the foreground from a command shell.  Then on Linux, send a kill -3 [PID] to JBoss to dump its thread state to stdout.  On Windows, you would [type Control-Break in the CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124672/java-stack-dump-on-windows) running JBoss.  Alternatively, use a monitoring tool like VisualVM.