# How to generate thread dump programmatically with ownable synchronizers?

Tags: java, java-8

I have seen this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965836/trigger-complete-stack-dump-programmatically) and also seen the [buildThreadDump()](https://github.com/netty/netty-build/blob/master/src/main/java/io/netty/build/junit/TimedOutTestsListener.java#L101) implementation from TimedOutTestsListener in few of the open source projects like (netty, apache-bookmark).

But the thread dump generated through the above approaches looks like below where the lock id and monitor id is not showing up. Can someone let me know how can I generate thread dump programmatically with locked synchronizer and condition ids?

```
"FlowStoreWarmer_flow_cache_warmup_thread-0" daemon prio=5 tid=4929 timed_waiting
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2083)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
"Time-limited test" daemon prio=5 tid=5038 blocked
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
        at com.vnera.storage.config.PolicyManager.setSystemValue(PolicyManager.java:259)
        at com.vnera.storage.utils.TestStorageUtils.tearDown(TestStorageUtils.java:265)
        at com.vnera.storage.utils.TestStorageUtils.afterTest(TestStorageUtils.java:310)
        at com.vnera.restapilayer.PinboardServiceTest.tearDown(PinboardServiceTest.java:393)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runAfters(MethodRoadie.java:150)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:102)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$LastRuleTestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```